# Continuity of the function $f(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(\sinh|x|)^\alpha} \frac{1}{(\sinh|2x-y|)^\beta} \frac{1}{(\sinh|x-y|)^\gamma} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $\alpha,\beta,\gamma>0$ and $\alpha+\beta+\gamma<1$. Then, one may show that the function
$$f(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(\sinh|x|)^\alpha} \frac{1}{(\sinh|2x-y|)^\beta} \frac{1}{(\sinh|x-y|)^\gamma} dx$$
is well-defined for every $y\in\mathbb R$.

I want to show that $f$ is continuous. The standard argument is to use the dominated convergence theorem, but this is hard since the singularity is "moving" as a function of $y$! In this case, how can I proceed?

Edit: I proved that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R-\{0\}$ by changing the variable $x=yz$ (JackT's comment). However, this method does not work for $y=0$. I also found out that enough to show that
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{|x|^\alpha} \frac{1}{|2x-y|^\beta} g(x-y) dx$$
is continuous at $y=0$, where $g$ is a continuous bounded function. This is obtained by the asymptotic expansion
$$\frac{1}{(\sinh|x|)^\alpha} - \frac{1}{|x|^\alpha} = O\left(|x|^{2-\alpha}\right).$$

Comment: How about making the change of variables $x=y z$ provided $y \neq 0$? Then the integrand only has a singularity at $z=0$, $z=1/2$ and $z=1$ so it may be easier to apply DCT.

Comment: @JackT Actually, I tried that right before, and I found out that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R-\{0\}$. But how about the continuity at $y=0$?

Comment: That's not an issue I think because you want to show the limit $f(y) \to f(y_0)$ as $y \to y_0$. If $y_0=0$ then you already have $y \neq 0$. If $y_0 \neq 0$ then for $y$ sufficiently close to $y_0$ you again can assume $y \neq 0$.

Comment: Actually, yeah I don't think that'll work for $y_0=0$

Comment: Continuity is local so you can dominate what’s inside the integral with respect to the parameter, locally.

Comment: @blamethelag Yes, so we may choose small $\epsilon>0$, and dominate the integrand, say, $\frac{1}{|2x-y|^\beta}$, as $\sup_{|y|<\epsilon} \frac{1}{|2x-y|^\beta}$. But this is $\infty$ for $|x|<\epsilon/2$!

Comment: Ok I see your problem